# Weird stuff happening while importing modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I hate to give the question this heading but I actually don't know whats happening so here it goes.

I was doing another project in which I wanted to use logging module. The code is distributed among few files & instead of creating separate logger objects for seperate files, I thought of creating a logs.py with contents

```
import sys, logging

class Logger:
    def __init__(self):
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s')
        stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger=logging.getLogger('')
        self.logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def debug(self, message):
        self.logger.debug(message)
```

and use this class like (in different files.)

```
import logs
b = logs.Logger()
b.debug("Hi from a.py")
```

1. I stripped down the whole problem to ask the question here. Now, I have 3 files, a.py, b.py & main.py. All 3 files instantiate the logs.Logger class and prints a debug message.
2. a.py & b.py **imports "logs"** and prints their debug message.
3. main.py **imports logs, a & b**; and prints it own debug message.

The file contents are like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ssr.png

**Why is debug message from b.py printed 2 times & from main.py 3 times?**

Comment: I think you need to give some details about the logging library.

Comment: Its from the standard library. http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Comment: Show the real code from `b.py` and `main.py` - the imports

Comment: @warvariuc The screenshot http://i.imgur.com/XoKVf.png displays the codes. In case you need text files to test something, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7728421/wierd.tar.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a name for the logger, otherwise you always use root logger.

```
import sys, logging

class Logger:
    def __init__(self, name):
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s')
        stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger=logging.getLogger(name)
        self.logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def debug(self, message):
        self.logger.debug(message)
```

http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial :

> A good convention to use when naming loggers is to use a module-level
>   logger, in each module which uses logging, named as follows:
>
> `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: Hmm. I just figured out that if I use this approach, my filename shown in the log is always my module name. So, probably this is not a nice way to use it. Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: Instead of `__name__` put any string you like. But be aware that the same name will get the same logger.

Answer (score 2):

`logging.getLogger('')` will return exactly the same object each time you call it. So each time you instantiate a `Logger` (why use old-style classes here?) you are attaching one more handler resulting in printing to one more target. As all your targets pointing to the same thing, the last call to `.debug()` will print to each of the three `StreamHandler` objects pointing to `sys.stdout` resulting in three lines being printed.

Comment: But, in each file, I save each reference of logging.getLogger() in a separate local variable. So, I am not really following. EDIT: OK. I get it, they are all getting registered to same root logger

Comment: `logging.getLogger(foo)` will return the same thing each time you ask for the same `foo`. So even though you save it to different variables, what you are saving is a reference to the same instance. For proper logging only call `logging.getLogger(your_loggin_domain)` in your modules and do a proper `logging` module configuration in your `main.py`. You don't need your own `Logger` class at all.

Comment: Thanks. What are the new-style classes btw?

Comment: They extend the `object` type and support things like `super`. http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/

Answer (score 1):

First.  Don't create your own class of `Logger`.

Just configure the existing logger classes with exising `logging` configuration tools.

Second.  Each time you create your own class of `Logger` you also create new handlers and then attach the new (duplicating) handler to the root logger.  This leads to duplication of messages.

If you have several modules that must (1) run stand-alone and (2) also run as part of a larger, composite, application, you need to do this.  This will assure that logging configuration is done only once.

```
import logging
logger= logging.getLogger( __file__ ) # Unique logger for a, b or main


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig( stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s' )
    # From this point forward, you can use the `logger` object.
    logger.info( "Hi" )
```

Comment: Thanks. I will change my code & use this. I should have given all the options in the constructor in the beginning itself. The only thing I was trying to do is save lines.

Comment: @shadyabhi: Trying to "save lines"?  This is two lines for a library module and a third line for a main module.  How could you make it any smaller?

Comment: I meant that I didnt use constructor like you did.

Comment: @shadyabhi: "I didnt use constructor"?  What does that mean?   The `getLogger()` function?  Or the `basicConfig()` function?  Were you trying to save one line of code by writing (testing and debugging) a complete class?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. All I wanted to say was that the reason I made a separate logs.py file was that I wanted to save lines of code. And in that logs.py I was setting options for logging module using separate functions which was taking so many lines. After I saw your coding style of using the constructor to give most of the options, I liked it. Therefore, I changed my code to implement it like your style. https://github.com/shadyabhi/SMSSender/blob/master/SMSSender.py